# install erlang on mac but got the error "crypto usable openssl found ...",how can i fixed it?

Tags: macos, erlang

i install erlang ENV on my mac, then excute './configure' and got the error like this :

```
*********************************************************************
**********************  APPLICATIONS DISABLED  **********************
*********************************************************************
crypto         : No usable OpenSSL found
odbc           : ODBC library - header check failed
ssh            : No usable OpenSSL found
ssl            : No usable OpenSSL found
*********************************************************************


*********************************************************************
**********************  DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION  ******************
*********************************************************************
documentation  :  
                fop is missing. 
                Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.
*********************************************************************
```

Comment: Apple decided not to us OpenSSL anymore because of security problems, so it doesn't come preinstalled on your computer, and your crappy installer doesn't know that.  Just install erlang yourself: http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#Advanced-configuration-and-build-of-ErlangOTP_Building_OS-X-Darwin.  Or, look for the myriad of posts on how to install OpenSSL on a mac.

Comment: thank you , but I resolve it do that: excute the "configure" with "--with-ssl" to assign the path of openssl.

Answer (score 1):

**It means OpenSSL was not found on your machine.** This is most likely due to it not being installed.

There are several ways to install OpenSSL on OSX, but the easiest way is to use [Homebrew to install it](http://brewformulas.org/Openssl). If you already have Homebrew itself installed you can just do:

```
brew install openssl
```

If you are just wanting to get Erlang installed and don't want to deal with manual configuration I would recommend checking out [kerl, a command line tool for building and install Erlang](https://github.com/kerl/kerl). It helps you avoid many of the issues you will run into building and configuring manually.

Comment: *This is most likely due to it not being installed.* -- 13 hours before you posted your answer the OP stated in the comments that specifying the path to OpenSSL in the configure command solved his problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MacOS with homebrew and asdf so it works for me to install openssl as @kangquanwang mention in the comment of the question

```
brew install openssl@1.1    
asdf uninstall erlang 24.3.4.15    
asdf install erlang 24.3.4.15 --with-ssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)
```